# Generic typecasting

Tags: c++, casting, c++14, generic-programming, type-deduction

I am using C++14 (can't use higher than this).

I have 3 structs:

```
struct TypeA {                    
    Header header;
    struct data {
        std::uint32_t d;                                           
    };
};

struct TypeB {                    
    Header header;
    struct data {
        std::uint32_t d;         
        std::uint16_t a;        
    };
};

struct TypeC {                    
    Header header;
    struct data {
        std::uint32_t d:20;     
        std::uint32_t a:12;     
    };
};
```

I also have a string, which is basically data received from a stream. After parsing the header (1st 60 bytes), I know what type of data (whether it is TypeA, TypeB or TypeC) is contained in the remainder of the string. Eventually I should be able to do something like:

```
//header.type = 1, 2 or 3
data_type = get_data_type(header.type);
data_type data = static_cast<data_type>((char*)str.c_str());;
```

How can I do this in a generic way without using too many if-else statements?

Comment: there are many libraries out there for de-/serialization. If you write your own you will have to have a switch on the type somewhere, though I dont understand why you are afraid of "too many if-else", I think you need exactly one, no?

Comment: I see no need to actually cast *anything*. Just read a naked header (the very reason it comes.. .at the *head*  ... is to assist in identifying what it about to come. Once you have the header, conditionally create whatever you know is coming and march on from there, possibly moving pre-read header into your now-known object being constructed). Sure, you could abstract it, but unless there are dozens of these types, why bother.

Comment: what wrong with auto data; instead of data_type data = static_cast<data_type>((char*)str.c_str());

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes it is `Header`, changed that now

Comment: Short answer: You can't, because C++ is statically typed and you cannot store a datatype in a variable. And you would require some kind of f construct anyway, to act on the data received

Comment: @santoshdhanawade, I will need data type for `static_cast` though, isn't it?
@MofX, yes I am aware of that, it was more of a "pseudo-code" to show what I want to do.

Comment: This is another XY problem.   It's not "generic typecasting" that you need.   You need a way to produce an object of required type, which depends on information specified in the header.    If it is possible to have a common polymorphic base class for your struct types (e.g. something that contains the `header` member), you could use some variant of a factory pattern to create an instance of the required type.   If there is no possibility of having a common base class, then there is no solution that doesn't involve undefined or unspecified behaviour.

Comment: cast is not required on auto. you can directly auto data = str.c_str();

Comment: @Peter base class is definitely possible. I will try this out.

Answer (score 2):

To not have if-statements you need a lookup table (or a switch statement) of the factory functions. Depending on how "nice" you want it to be you can either initialize the table at run-time or have compiler generate it for you with a bit of static initialization magic.

Run-time version would be something like:

```cpp
using prefix_t = decltype(Header.type);
using myvar_t = std::variant<StructA, StructB, StructC>;
using factory_t = std::function<myvar_t(body_buffer_t)>;
std::map<prefix_t, factory_t> factories;

// this can be improved with static initialization so factories would register themselves
factories[HeaderOfStructA] = ...;
factories[HeaderOfStructB] = ...;
factories[HeaderOfStructC] = ...;
```

Comment: Interesting option.